# Badbox from PGF layer using fit

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit, badness

Why does the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\tikzstyle{internal} = [draw, fill, shape=circle]
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape,node distance=1.4cm,semithick]
  \node[internal] (0)                    {};
  \node[internal] (1) [right       of=0] {};
  \node[internal] (2) [above right of=1] {};
  \node[internal] (3) [above       of=2] {};
  \node[internal] (4) [below right of=1] {};
  \node[internal] (5) [below       of=4] {};
  \node[internal] (6) [below right of=2] {};
  \node[internal] (7) [right       of=6] {};
  \path (0) edge node[near end]   (e1) {} (1)
        (2) edge node[near start] (e2) {} (3)
        (4) edge node[near start] (e3) {} (5)
        (6) edge node[near start] (e4) {} (7);
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node[draw=blue!60,thick,rounded corners,fit = (e1) (e2) (e4)] {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

have a bad box (see the [log file here](http://pastebin.com/LvsQevfY)), while this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\tikzstyle{internal} = [draw, fill, shape=circle]
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape,node distance=1.4cm,semithick]
  \node[internal] (0)                    {};
  \node[internal] (1) [right       of=0] {};
  \node[internal] (2) [above right of=1] {};
  \node[internal] (3) [above       of=2] {};
  \node[internal] (4) [below right of=1] {};
  \node[internal] (5) [below       of=4] {};
  \node[internal] (6) [below right of=2] {};
  \node[internal] (7) [right       of=6] {};
  \path (0) edge node[near end]   (e1) {} (1)
        (2) edge node[near start] (e2) {} (3)
        (4) edge node[near start] (e3) {} (5)
        (6) edge node[near start] (e4) {} (7);
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node[draw=blue!60,thick,rounded corners,fit = (e1) (e2) (e3)] {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(where "e4" is changed to "e3" in the 4th-to-last line) with output

[image]

does not have a bad box (see the [log file here](http://pastebin.com/ptqWSYKy))?

Comment: Hm, interesting! The combination `(e2) (e4)` in the `fit` doesn't produce an underfull box either, while `(e1) (e4)` does.

Comment: I have no problem with your examples (TeXLive 2011 and TikZ/PGF 2.10).

Comment: @PolGab My friend has TeXLive 2011 but still has a badbox, see [his log file](http://pastebin.com/0WkKhqj9).

Comment: @TysonWilliams Sorry... I have used TeXLive 2011 and TikZ/pgf **CVS** version.

Answer (score 9):

Surprisingly simple issue: This comes from the fact that the `fit` key adjusts the size of the fitted node by setting the `text width` key while also activating `text centered`. Your nodes `e1` and `e4` are so wide apart that the text in your node (well, the empty text) can't be centered without introducing too much stretch on either side. When you only fit your node around `e1` and `e3`, the stretch isn't large enough to trigger the `underfull` warning.

A simpler MWE to demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={outer sep=0pt}]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3.1cm,1);
\node [draw, fit=(A) (B)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This generates an `underfull` warning. If we adjust the position of `(B)` to `(3.0cm,1)`, the warning disappears. Even simpler, if we have

```
\node [
    text centered,
    text width=3.1cm,
] {};
```

we get the `underfull` warning as well (no `fit` involved at all). Changing `text width` to `3.0cm` gets rid of the warning.

So what you can do to get rid of the warnings in your code: Set `every fit/.append style=text badly centered`. That style tells TikZ to also center the text, but to be more relaxed about too much stretch. In the CVS version, the `fit` library uses this key by default, which is why PolGab couldn't reproduce the error.

<sub>Actually, since you're not using text at all, you could also set `align=left` or `align=right` to get rid of the warning, but using `text badly centered` is a good idea anyway.</sub>

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for being so helpful. There is no way that I would have ever figured out why this was happening.

Question though: I have many figures in a paper with this problem. Do I need to have `every fit...` be an option on each tikzpicture environment or is there a way to make this a global option that applies to all tikzpicture environments?

Comment: You can just use `\tikzset{every fit/.append style...` in your preamble.