# Can't get rid of strange underfull \hbox with TikZ fit library

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, fit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badbox from PGF layer using fit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61064/badbox-from-pgf-layer-using-fit)

This peace of code is compiled with 'Underfull \hbox (badness 1484) in paragraph at lines 23--23' message. Line 23 is `\node[draw, inner sep = 10pt, fit=(MUL1) (MUL2)] {};`. How can I get rid of underfull box?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw]                  (MUL1) {MUL1};
  \node[draw, right = of MUL1] (MUL2) {MUL2};

  \node[left =  of MUL1] (A) {A};
  \node[right = of MUL2] (B) {B};

  \draw[->] (A)    -- (MUL1);
  \draw[->] (MUL1) -- (MUL2);
  \draw[->] (MUL2) -- (B);

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[draw, inner sep = 10pt, fit=(MUL1) (MUL2)] {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This looks like it probably is a duplicate of the question that Jake points to.  It currently has 4 votes to close as a duplicate.  Could someone with the right version of TikZ (I have the CVS) please verify that the solution there does solve this one before anyone casts the final vote-to-close as duplicate?

Comment: (Someone just verified it for me in chat.  I shan't name David Carlisle as he doesn't want it known that he has compiled a document using TikZ.  Anyway, confirmed as duplicate.)

Answer (score 3):

It has something to do with the empty node.

Writing

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
 \node[draw, inner sep = 10pt, fit=(MUL1) (MUL2)] {\hspace*{\fill}~};
\end{pgfonlayer}%
```

instead will get rid of the underfull error.  Seems there's got to be a better way to achieve your effect.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the `fit` library of TikZ/pgf (v2.10). With the [latest CVS version of TikZ/pgf](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/tikz-pgf.html) (cf. my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/#63982) to [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044)), your MWE compiles without error or warning.